# MariaDB Replication - Missing ^M Characters on Slave

Tags: replication, mariadb, mariadb-10.2

I've got a simple single master->slave replication setup with MIXED binlog format for mariadb 10.2.22-1 on RHEL7.

I believe I'm having an issue where '^M' characters in a longtext column are not being replicated to the slave.

I've checked the encoding matches on both databases (SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collat%' and SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%').

Does anyone know what might be causing the slave to strip the '^M' character when the data is being replicated to the slave?

Comment: Is one machine Windows and the other *nix?

Comment: Nope, both are *nix (RHEL7).

Comment: Please provide `SELECT HEX(col) ...` on both the Master and Slave for some small row with a `^M` that disappeared.  What charset and collation are you using?  For _most_, ^M is handled the same.